# Getting Border with Carousel in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a Problem with Carousel From Sencha Touch 2. I'm getting a border around my App in iPhone. What should I have to do to remove this border from app?

Here is my Code:

```
var mainPanel = ({
    xtype: 'carousel',
    id: 'playersView',
    ui: 'light',
    flex: 1,
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },
    items: [
        playerLiveMonitorView,
        blackPlayerLiveMonitorVie
    ]
});

var topPanel = ({
    xtype: 'panel',
    width: '100%',
    height: '10%',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            width: '100%',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',

            },
            items: [
                serverBtnPanel,
                logoImagePanel
            ]
        },
        roundImagePanel
    ]
});

this.add([topPanel, mainPanel]);
```

Comment: attach screen shot please

Comment: What id `this`? Add its code also.

Comment: There might be something wrong in your app.css file. I used to have a white border around the app when there was unsolved Git conflicts in app.css.